# Работа мьютекса с главным потоком (C++)

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Всем привет, предположим, есть некая функция, выполняющаяся в каком-то потоке:

```
void Read() {
   lock_guard<mutex>(someMutex); // защищаем разделяемые данные мьютексом
   // что-то там читается, ну, например, из сокета..
}
```

Так вот у меня вопрос: если эта функция будет выполняться в разных потоках, то, естественно, проблема гонки данных решится, и одновременно данные читаться не будут, но если вызвать этот метод явно в главном потоке с учётом, что в этот момент его вызывает какой-то другой поток, что будет? В моей практике мне показалось, что мьютекс не заблокирует работу мейновского потока, и как раз прочтётся одновременно, или я не прав?

Comment: Если вы всё делаете правильно, должен заблокировать. Мьютекс не знает, главный ваш поток или нет.

Comment: Его заблокирует тот поток, который успеет сделать это первым - и неважно это основной поток приложения или нет